# Reload a page after successfully submit a form using ajax

Tags: php, ajax, asynchronous

I am currently a making a log in form using ajax

```
<div id='error3'></div>
<input type='email' required name='email' id='email' placeholder='Email'>
<input type='password' required name='password' id='password' placeholder='password'>
<input type='submit'  name='submit99' id='submit' value='login'>
```

my java script is

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#submit").click(function(){
        var emailnew = $("#email").val();
        var  password = $("#password").val();

        var dataString = '&email='+ email + '&password='+ password;
        if(emailnew==''|| password='')
        {
            document.getElementById('error3').innerHTML="Please Fill All Fields";
        }
        else
        {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "process.php",
                data: dataString,
                cache: false,
                success: function(result){
                    document.getElementById('error3').innerHTML=result;
                }

            });
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

and my process.php script is

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['email']))
{
    if (filter_var($email99, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
    {
        $con=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','password','database');
        $query="SELECT * FROM TABLENAME WHERE USER='' AND PASSWORD=''";
        $result=mysqli_query($con,$query);
        if(mysqli_num_rows($result)!=0)
        {
            echo "You are successfully logged in";
login user
start a cookie or session
    }
        else
        {
            echo "You are bot a valid user";
        }
    }
    else
        echo "not a valid email";
}
?>
```

now if we recive a message "You are successfully logged in" refresh the current page otherwise show only error message and do not refresh the page.

i have a choice of adding

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="30">
```

but this works only in chrome not in firefox.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put the condtion inside loop `success: function(result){`

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#submit").click(function () {
            var emailnew = $("#email").val();
            var password = $("#password").val();

            var dataString = '&email=' + email + '&password=' + password;
            if (emailnew == '' || password = '') {
                document.getElementById('error3').innerHTML = "Please Fill All Fields";
            } else {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "process.php",
                    data: dataString,
                    cache: false,
                    success: function (result) {
                        if (result == "You are successfully logged in") {
                            document.location.href = 'login.htm';
                        } else {
                            document.getElementById('error3').innerHTML = result;
                        }
                    }

                });
            }
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#submit").click(function () {
            var emailnew = $("#email").val();
            var password = $("#password").val();

            var dataString = '&email=' + email + '&password=' + password;
            if (emailnew == '' || password = '') {
                document.getElementById('error3').innerHTML = "Please Fill All Fields";
            }
            else {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "process.php",
                    data: dataString,
                    cache: false,
                    success: function (result) {
                        document.getElementById('error3').innerHTML = result;
                        if (result == "You are bot a valid user") {
                            window.location.href = "mypage.html"
                        }
                    }

                });
            }
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#submit").click(function(){
            var emailnew = $("#email").val();
            var  password = $("#password").val();

            var dataString = '&email='+ email + '&password='+ password;
            if(emailnew == null || password == null)
            {
                document.getElementById('error3').innerHTML="Please Fill All Fields";
            }
            else
            {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "process.php",
                    data: dataString,
                    cache: false,
                    success: function(result)
                    {
                        if(result == "logged in true")
                        {
                            window.setTimeout(function(){location.reload()},1000); //reload with time
                            location.reload(); //reload without time
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            document.getElementById('error3').innerHTML=result;
                        }


                    }

                });
            }
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

your process.php should return back a result like successfull (true) and unsuccessful (false) flag. or userID for example if it was successful and some other flags if it wasn't. you shouldn't echo the notifications in your proccess.php file. then you can have something like this in your javascript code:

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "process.php",
   data: dataString,  
   cache: false,
   success: function(result){
      if(result=='successful'){
          showMessageAndredirectFunction();
          //in this functionyou can show the message in your html page like the way you do for error and with a delay redirect the page with javascript
      else
        document.getElementById('error3').innerHTML="Bad usernaem or password";
   }});
```

you can set the session in your process.php if it was successful yet.

Answer (score 0):

`window.location.reload()` is used for reloading the page by using javascript.
or you can use `window.location.href=window.location.href;`