# Reload or Refresh Page after comment successfully submitted in Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to reload the page after the comment is successfully submitted 
Comment submitted through Ajax

After this line

```
// Save the comment
        $state = $comment->store();
```

If i am trying to use location.reload(); as

```
    // Save the comment
            $state = $comment->store();
location.reload();
```

then its not working and comment not even submitting
Below is complete code
Can any one help - how to refresh and load page when comment is successfully submitted and stored in backend

```
<?php
defined('_JEXEC') or die('Unauthorized Access');

require_once(JPATH_COMPONENT . '/views/views.php');

class EasyBlogViewComments extends EasyBlogView
{
    /**
     * Processes comment saving
     *
     * @since   4.0
     * @access  public
     * @param   string
     * @return
     */
    public function save()
    {
        // Check for request forgeries
        EB::checkToken();

        // Test if user is really allowed to post comments
        if (!$this->acl->get('allow_comment')) {
            return $ajax->reject(JText::_('COM_EASYBLOG_NO_PERMISSION_TO_POST_COMMENT'));
        }

        // Default values
        $moderated = false;
        $parentId = $this->input->get('parentId', 0, 'int');
        $depth = $this->input->get('depth', 0, 'int');
        $subscribe = $this->input->get('subscribe', false, 'bool');
        $email = $this->input->get('email', '', 'email');
        $message = $this->input->get('comment', '', 'default');
        $name = $this->input->get('name', '', 'default');
        $username = $this->input->get('username', '', 'default');
        $password = $this->input->get('password', '', 'default');
        $title = $this->input->get('title', '', 'default');
        $terms = $this->input->get('terms', false, 'bool');
        $blogId = $this->input->get('blogId', 0, 'int');
        $isCB = $this->input->get('iscb', 0, 'int');

        // If there is no name, and the current user is logged in, use their name instead
        if (!$name && $this->my->id) {
            $user = EB::user($this->my->id);
            $name = $user->getName();
        }

        // Validate the email
        $data = array('post_id' => $blogId, 'comment' => $message, 'title' => $title, 'email' => $email, 'name' => $name, 'username' => $username, 'terms' => $terms);

        // Load up comment table
        $comment = EB::table('Comment');
        $state = $comment->validatePost($data);

        if (!$state) {
            return $this->ajax->reject($comment->getError());
        }

        // Bind the data on the comment table now
        $comment->bindPost($data);

        // Check for spams
        if ($comment->isSpam()) {
            return $this->ajax->reject(JText::_('COM_EASYBLOG_SPAM_DETECTED_IN_COMMENT'));
        }

        $captchaResponse = EB::captcha()->verify();

        // Perform captcha verification
        if (isset($captchaResponse->success) && $captchaResponse->success == false) {
            return $this->ajax->reject($captchaResponse->errorCodes);
        }

        // Get current date
        $date = EB::date();

        // Set other attributes for the comment
        $comment->created = $date->toSql();
        $comment->modified = $date->toSql();
        $comment->published = true;
        $comment->parent_id = $parentId;
        $comment->created_by = $this->my->id;

        // Process user registrations via comment
        $register = $this->input->get('register', '', 'bool');

        if ($register && $this->my->guest) {

            if (empty($password) || empty($username) || empty($email)) {
                return $this->ajax->reject('COM_EASYBLOG_COMMENT_REGISTRATION_FIELD_EMPTY');
            }

            $userModel = EB::model('Users');
            $id = $userModel->createUser($username, $email, $name, $password);

            if (!is_numeric($id)) {
                return $this->ajax->reject($id);
            }

            $comment->created_by = $id;
        }

        $totalComments = $this->input->get('totalComment', 0, 'int');


        // Determines if comment moderation is enabled
        if ($this->config->get('comment_moderatecomment') == 1 || ($this->my->guest && $this->config->get('comment_moderateguestcomment'))) {
            $comment->published = EBLOG_COMMENT_STATUS_MODERATED;
        }

        // Load up the blog table
        $blog = EB::table('Blog');
        $blog->load($comment->post_id);

        // If moderation for author is disabled, ensure that the comment is also published automatically.
        if ((!$this->config->get('comment_moderateauthorcomment') && $blog->created_by == $this->my->id) || EB::isSiteAdmin()) {
            $comment->published = true;
        }

        // Update the ordering of the comment before storing
        $comment->updateOrdering();

        // Save the comment
        $state = $comment->store();


        if (!$state) {
            return $this->ajax->reject($comment->getError());
        }

        $resultMessage = JText::_('COM_EASYBLOG_COMMENTS_POSTED_SUCCESS');
        $resultState = 'success';



        // If user registered as well, display a proper message
        if ($register) {
            $resultMessage = JText::_('COM_EASYBLOG_COMMENTS_SUCCESS_AND_REGISTERED');
        }

        if ($comment->isModerated()) {
            $resultMessage = JText::_('COM_EASYBLOG_COMMENT_POSTED_UNDER_MODERATION');
            $resultState = 'info';
        }

        // Process comment subscription
        if ($subscribe && $this->config->get('main_subscription') && $blog->subscription) {
            $subscribeModel = EB::model('Subscription');
            $subscribeModel->subscribe('blog', $blog->id, $email, $name, $this->my->id);
        }

        // Process comment notifications
        $comment->processEmails($comment->isModerated(), $blog);

        // Set the comment depth
        $comment->depth = $this->input->get('depth', 0, 'int');

        // Update the sent flag
        $comment->updateSent();

        // Format the comments
        $result = EB::comment()->format(array($comment));
        $comment = $result[0];

        $language = JFactory::getLanguage();
        $rtl = $language->isRTL();

        $theme = EB::template();
        $theme->set('comment', $comment);
        $theme->set('rtl', $rtl);

        $output = '';

        if ($isCB) {
            // if the is saving from CB plugin, then we need to display the output using different template.
            $output = $theme->output('site/comments/cb.item');
        } else {
            $output = $theme->output('site/comments/default.item');
        }

        return $this->ajax->resolve($output, $resultMessage, $resultState);
    }
public function reloadCaptcha()
{
    $ajax = EB::ajax();

    // Get the previous captcha id.
    $id   = $this->input->get('previousId', 0, 'int');

    $captcha = EB::table('Captcha');
    $state = $captcha->load($id);

    if ($state) {
        $captcha->delete();
    }

    // Generate a new captcha
    $captcha = EB::table('Captcha');
    $captcha->created = EB::date()->toSql();
    $captcha->store();

    $image = EB::_('index.php?option=com_easyblog&task=captcha.generate&tmpl=component&no_html=1&id=' . $captcha->id, false);

    return $ajax->resolve($image, $captcha->id);
}
```

2nd File

```
EasyBlog.module('comments/form', function($) {

    var module = this;

    EasyBlog.require()
    .script('comments/captcha', 'comments/list')
    .library('markitup')
    .done(function($) {

        EasyBlog.Controller('Comments.Form', {
            defaultOptions: {

                "{formWrapper}": "[data-comment-form-wrapper]",
                "{form}": "[data-comment-form]",
                "{title}": "[data-comment-title]",
                "{name}": "[data-comment-name]",
                "{username}": "[data-comment-username]",
                "{password}": "[data-comment-password]",
                "{email}": "[data-comment-email]",
                "{register}": "[data-comment-register]",
                "{website}": "[data-comment-website]",
                "{counter}": "[data-comment-counter]",
                "{subscribe}" : "[data-comment-subscribe]",
                "{terms}": "[data-comment-terms]",
                "{tncLink}": "[data-comment-tnc]",
                "{parentId}" : "[data-comment-parent-id]",
                "{commentDepth}": "[data-comment-depth]",
                "{blogId}" : "[data-comment-blog-id]",
                "{depth}": "[data-comment-depth]",
                "{notice}": "[data-comment-notice]",
                "{editor}": "[data-comment-editor]",
                "{submit}": "[data-comment-submit]",
                "{formToken}": "[data-comment-token]",

                "{recaptcha}": "[data-recaptcha-item]"
            }
        }, function(self, opts, base) {

            return {

                init: function() {

                    self.initEditor();

                    self.list = self.addPlugin('list');

                    // If recaptcha is enabled, we should skip the normal captcha
                    var recaptcha = self.recaptcha.inside(self.element).length;

                    if (recaptcha < 1) {
                        self.captcha = self.addPlugin('captcha');
                    }
                },

                initEditor: function() {
                    if (self.editor().data('comment-bbcode') == 1) {
                        self.editor().markItUp(window.EasyBlogBBCodeSettings);
                    }
                },

                setNotice: function(message, type) {
                    var className = '';

                    if (type == 'error') {
                        className = 'alert-danger';
                    }

                    if (type == 'success') {
                        className = 'alert-success';
                    }

                    if (type == 'info') {
                        className = 'alert-info';
                    }

                    self.notice()
                        .removeClass('hide')
                        .addClass('alert ' + className)
                        .html(message);
                },

                resetForm: function() {
                    // If the comment form has a parent id, we need to reposition the comment form back.
                    var parentId = self.parentId().val();

                    if (parentId != 0) {
                        self.form().appendTo(self.formWrapper());
                    }

                    // Reset the form
                    self.username().val('');
                    self.password().val('');
                    self.subscribe().attr('checked', false);
                    self.editor().val('');
                    self.website().val('');
                    self.name().val('');
                    self.depth().val(0);
                    self.parentId().val(0);

                    self.trigger('resetForm');

                    // Determine if recaptcha is available
                    var recaptcha = self.recaptcha.inside(self.element);

                    // Get recaptcha's response
                    if (recaptcha.length > 0) {
                        grecaptcha.reset();
                    }
                },

                resetNotice: function() {
                    self.notice()
                        .removeClass('info error')
                        .html('');
                },

                "{self} replyComment": function(el, event, commentItem, commentId, commentDepth) {
                    // Hide notices in the reply form
                    self.notice().addClass('hide');

                    // When user tries to reply to an existing comment, move the form next to the level of the comment item
                    commentItem.after(self.form());

                    self.depth().val(commentDepth);

                    // Set the new parent id to the comment's id
                    self.parentId().val(commentId);
                },

                "{self} cancelReply": function(el, event, commentItem, commentId) {
                    // Set the parent id to 0
                    self.parentId().val(0);

                    // Reset the comment depth back to 0
                    self.depth().val(0);

                    // Relocate the form back to it's origin
                    self.formWrapper().html(self.form());
                },

                "{self} commentAdded": function()
                {
                    // Increment the counter
                    var count = self.counter().html();
                        count = parseInt(count) + 1;

                    self.counter().html(count.toString());
                    self.resetForm();
                },

                getValues: function() {

                    var data = {

                        title: self.title().val(),
                        name: self.name().val(),
                        email: self.email().val(),
                        username: self.username().val(),
                        password: self.password().val(),
                        website: self.website().val(),
                        subscribe: self.subscribe().is(':checked') ? 1 : 0,
                        register: self.register().is(':checked') ? 1 : 0,
                        comment: self.editor().val(),
                        terms: self.terms().is(':checked') ? 1 : 0,
                        depth: self.depth().val(),
                        parentId: self.parentId().val(),
                        blogId: self.blogId().val()
                    };

                    // token
                    // data[self.formToken().attr('name')] = 1;

                    // Determine if recaptcha is available
                    var recaptcha = self.recaptcha.inside(self.element);

                    // Get recaptcha's response
                    if (recaptcha.length > 0) {
                        data.recaptcha = grecaptcha.getResponse();
                    }

                    self.trigger('submitComment', [data]);
                    return data;
                },

                "{tncLink} click": function() {
                    EasyBlog.dialog({
                        content: EasyBlog.ajax('site/views/comments/terms')
                    })
                },

                "{submit} click" : function(el, event) {

                    event.preventDefault();

                    // Reset notices
                    self.resetNotice();

                    // Add loading indicator on the button
                    $(el).attr('disabled', true);

                    var tmp = $(el).html();

                    $(el).html('<i class="fa fa-repeat fa-spin"></i>');

                    // Get the form values
                    var data = self.getValues();

                    // Perform an ajax call to submit the comment
                    EasyBlog.ajax('site/views/comments/save', data)
                        .done(function(output, message, state) {

                            self.setNotice(message, state);
                            self.trigger('commentAdded',[output, data]);




                        })
                        .fail(function(message) {
                            self.setNotice(message, 'error');
                        })
                        .always(function(){
                            $(el).removeAttr('disabled');
                            $(el).html(tmp);

                            self.trigger('reloadCaptcha');
                        });

                    return false;
                }
            }
        });

        module.resolve();
    });
});
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31201838/reload-a-page-after-successfully-submit-a-form-using-ajax?rq=1

Comment: use the ajax callback function to do `location.reload()`?

Comment: @RamRaider - Sorry but am naive - if can advise on which line to use location.reload

Comment: your question states `ajax` but you have not shown the actual ajax function so it is hard to tell you exactly but within the javascript function there will be ( most likely ) some form of callback function that handles any responses from the server. It is within that callback that you would call `location.reload()` when you know the request succeeded

Comment: @RamRaider - i have tried adding the file probably which is the actual ajax function in the question asked. If can help where to put location.reload() in it

Answer (score 0):

I would hazard a guess that the place to add the `location.reload()` would be within this snippet:

```
"{self} commentAdded": function()
{
    // Increment the counter
    var count = self.counter().html();
        count = parseInt(count) + 1;

    self.counter().html(count.toString());
    self.resetForm();
},
```

So perhaps like:

```
"{self} commentAdded": function()
{
    // Increment the counter
    var count = self.counter().html();
        count = parseInt(count) + 1;

    self.counter().html(count.toString());
    self.resetForm();

    /* reload */
    location.reload();
},
```

Or, you could add it to the `.done` method within `EasyBlog.ajax` .... pretty much the same thing I think by looking at the code though

Comment: Thanks - tried adding     location.reload(); in above and also in .done function but unfortunately the page is not reloaded. Although the comment is submitted on fly but as ajax without page been refreshed

Comment: :( try putting an alert statement in at either location and see if it pops up an alert message - just as a test

Comment: I could well have misinterpreted the code but that was what looked likely to me as it referenced ajax